# How to customize tick mark for 2D surface plotply in both x axis (time of day) & y axis (dates in a year)

Tags: time-series, timestamp, ticker

I have this data set of high-frequency data of air temperature, with the intraday data from 00:00 to 23:55 (every 5 min) so it consists of 288 observations for the x-axis. And the other axis (y-axis) for dates in six continuous years from 2015-2020, in which 2016 and 2020 are leap years. So the surface is the surface of 288 (ncolumn) * 2192 (nrow), showing the values of air temperature in z axis. I have used plotply to plot the surface, however, the axis are now by numbering, i.e., the x-axis is like from 0 to 288 and the y-axis is from 0 to 2192. I want to customize these both axis, so that it appears as 00:00 to 23:55 in x-axis & 2015 to 2020 in y-axis. I have played around with plotly in R (scene, add-surface...) but there is no result for now. Is there anyone that can help with this? Thank you!